# Error signing in the specified account. please choose a different account

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I was trying to get connection with google drive and pick all files into a list activity. I have done it successfully using the google tutorial and solution steps. 
For your more unified reference let me inform you I have mainly followed the link below:
[https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/l7W9ofgDjDU)
using "BaseDemoActivity" and "PickFileWithOpenerActivity" class the application is working very fine in development environment. After all are working well I had made the application an apk file. And when I was trying to run that apk into another device or same device its providing me the message, "Error signing in the specified account. please choose a different account." sometime it's provide different message like: "unknown issue with Google play services". I don't really understand why I am having this kind of messages, where have i made my mistake. but believe me, on development environment everything is fine. Here I'm providing you my full codes, for your better understanding.

lib:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
```

BaseDemoActivity.class

```
public abstract class BaseDemoActivity extends Activity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "BaseDriveActivity";

/**
 * DriveId of an existing folder to be used as a parent folder in
 * folder operations samples.
 */
public static final String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = "0B2EEtIjPUdX6MERsWlYxN3J6RU0";

/**
 * DriveId of an existing file to be used in file operation samples..
 */
public static final String EXISTING_FILE_ID = "0ByfSjdPVs9MZTHBmMVdSeWxaNTg";

/**
 * Extra for account name.
 */
protected static final String EXTRA_ACCOUNT_NAME = "account_name";

/**
 * Request code for auto Google Play Services error resolution.
 */
protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;

/**
 * Next available request code.
 */
protected static final int NEXT_AVAILABLE_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

/**
 * Google API client.
 */
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/**
 * Called when activity gets visible. A connection to Drive services need to
 * be initiated as soon as the activity is visible. Registers
 * {@code ConnectionCallbacks} and {@code OnConnectionFailedListener} on the
 * activities itself.
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

/**
 * Handles resolution callbacks.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

/**
 * Called when activity gets invisible. Connection to Drive service needs to
 * be disconnected as soon as an activity is invisible.
 */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

/**
 * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is connected.
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
}

/**
 * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is disconnected.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}

/**
 * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is trying to connect but failed.
 * Handle {@code result.getResolution()} if there is a resolution is
 * available.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        return;
    }
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Shows a toast message.
 */
public void showMessage(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

/**
 * Getter for the {@code GoogleApiClient}.
 */
public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
  return mGoogleApiClient;
 }
}
```

PickFileWithOpenerActivity.class

```
public class PickFileWithOpenerActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

private static final String TAG = "PickFileWithOpenerActivity";

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = 1;

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
            .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
            .setMimeType(new String[] { "text/plain", "text/html" })
            .build(getGoogleApiClient());
    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(
                intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 1 && data != null){
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    DriveId driveId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
                            OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                    showMessage("Selected file's ID: " + driveId);
                }
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.googledrivetestandroidapplication" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name="com.example.googledrivetestandroidapplication.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PickFileWithOpenerActivity" />
</application>
```

#### Note: I have maintained the [Google Developers Console][2], project name with my developed project name, and the package name as,

```
package="com.example.googledrivetestandroidapplication"
```

in manifest.xml, in additional information i have use the build.gradle.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

I also tried in different way, like; reference from [Silvana L](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/l7W9ofgDjDU). Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. What am I suppose to do?

Clear Google Play Services cache (Settings > Application Manager > Google Play Services > Clear cache).
Turn off/on Google Play Services (Settings > Application Manager > Google Play Services > Turn off). After this, you may need to update via Google Play again.
Sign out/in of your Google Account across your phone.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understand your problem.

Please follow step to register app on google api console:-

1. Create New project in Api Console [GoogleApiConsole](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0)
2. In *API & auth* tab ---> *Credentials* ---> *Create new Client ID*
3. Select *Installed application* and Select *Android*
4. Register You app (*com.example.googledrivetestandroidapplication*) here with your *Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1)*

Answer (score 1):

You have created credential using android key,you need to create credential using oauth 2.0 .

Go to GoogleApiConsole,open your project then go to

API & auth tab ---> Credentials ---> Add Credentials ---> Oauth  2.0 Client ID

[image]
then enter application information